# How to checked a checkbox if exists value from database

Tags: php, checkbox

I have a question for you, I need to checked an checkbox if the value exists, Help me please, I tried but I have no results,
My code php is:

```
       <?php if($all_method_use): ?>
            <?php foreach($all_method_use as $method_use): ?><br/>
                  <input class="marg-left-10" style="margin-right: 5px;" value="<?php echo $method_use['name'] ?>"
                  <?php $i = 0; ?>
                  <?php foreach($d['technique_folosita'] as $t): ?>
                     <?php if($t[$i] == $method_use['name'] ): ?>
                         checked
                     <?php endif; $i++;  ?>
                   <?php endforeach; ?>
                   type="checkbox" id="methods[]" name="methods[]"/>
                   <?php echo $method_use['name'] ?>
             <?php endforeach; ?>
       <?php endif; ?>
```

I want to verify if $t[$i] == $method_use['name'] then checked the checkbox
My array:

```
[technique_folosita] => Array
            (
                [0] => first
                [1] => last
            )

[sistem_coordonate] => axa XOX
```

Help me please

Comment: do you see the HTML but only the 'checked' is missing? or are you getting an error

Comment: [Why are you using `$t[$i]` instead of just `$t`, `$t` should already be the value you're looking for.](https://eval.in/194629)

Answer (score 0):

```
echo '<input class="marg-left-10" style="margin-right: 5px;" value="' . $method_use['name'] . '"';

foreach($d['technique_folosita'] as $t) {
    if($t[$i] == $method_use['name']) {
        echo 'checked';
        break;
    }
}

echo 'type="checkbox" id="methods[]" name="methods[]"/>';
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
<?php if($all_method_use): ?>
            <?php foreach($all_method_use as $method_use): ?><br/>
                  <input class="marg-left-10" style="margin-right: 5px;" value="<?php echo $method_use['name'] ?>"
                  <?php $i = 0; ?>
                  <?php foreach($d['technique_folosita'] as $t): ?>
                     <?php if($t[$i] == $method_use['name'] ): ?>
                         checked
                     <?php endif; $i++;  ?>
                   <?php endforeach; ?>
                   type="checkbox" id="methods[]" name="methods[]" <?php if($t[$i] == $method_user['name']) { ?>checked="checked" <?php } ?>/>
                   <?php echo $method_use['name'] ?>
             <?php endforeach; ?>
   <?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you can follow more cleanest way:

```
<?php if (..true..): ?>

<input type="checkbox" checked="checked" />

<?php else: ?>

<input type="checkbox" />

<?php endif; ?>
```